# prevent duplicate Browser/Activity launching

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way of preventing a duplicate launch of browser/activity, while the user is already focused on it.

mybe there is a way to detect before if the user's current screen is already focused on the same activity/browser i intent to launch?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 0):

check out the following intent flag http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

what about:   FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT?

Comment: Well i tried this:
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

it didnt work.. the browser still jumped to the intent page.

Answer (score 0):

what about: FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT?

Comment: The first answer was how I do it in my app to prevent duplicate activities. I guess I do not understand your question.